# is there any way to get list of apps that are installed manually in ios using xamain ios?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Unable to find the solution to get list of apps installed in iphone device using xamarin ios.

is it possible or apple is allowing to achieve it?

#include <objc/runtime.h>

```
Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
SEL selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];

SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
NSLog(@"apps: %@", [workspace performSelector:selectorALL]);
```

is the solution i have seen but couldn’t found equivalent code in xamarin native ios.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
NSObject LSApplicationWorkspace_class = new NSObject(ObjCRuntime.Class.GetHandle("LSApplicationWorkspace"));
NSObject workspace = LSApplicationWorkspace_class.PerformSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("defaultWorkspace"));
var list = workspace.PerformSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("allApplications"));
```

**Note:**  LSApplicationWorkspace is private api, if you use it and want to upload your app to app store, it will get rejected. So it's not recommended that you use it in your project.

Comment: Hi Liyun Zhang thanks for the code but  the above code is returning null .

Comment: I tested on the simulator and it worked. What kind of device did you test on? @prashanth

Comment: I Tested in iphone 11 pro device

Comment: for simulators its working fine but , physical device its not.

Comment: This should be the limit in the ios. You can post an issue on the apple comunity.